# Python, apply a function to a pandas data frame where the data is an argument

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a function to a pandas data frame.
One of the arguments passed into the function is the cell's value.

I'm pretty new to pandas, so I'm wondering how to exactly pull it off.

```py
 def filter_bags_only(bag, item):
    if len(item) == bag:
        return item


planes_bag_df = items_df['Bags'].applymap(func=filter_bags_only(bag=PLANES_LEN,item= # how to map this to the colunm items_df['Bags']? ))
```

If I run without assigning item:

```py
   planes_bag_df = items_df['Bags'].apply(func=filter_bags_only(bag=PLANES_LEN))
```

I get this straightforward error.

```
TypeError: filter_bags_only() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

Comment: hey Yovel, any chance of a sample input & output?

Comment: `apply()` should pass the entire row, column, or cell to the function. Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: of  the function?

Comment: @AMC added error

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get you correct, but based on what I understand here is something to look in the direction of:

```py
items_df['bag_len'] = item_df['Bags'].map(len)
planes_bag_df = item_df.query('bag_len == @PLANES_LEN')
```

I am assuming `PLANES_LEN` is a scalar. Please post more details if the above does not solve your problem.

Comment: It workes great, But when trying to make the function more generic:


def base_bags_query(len_of_bag):
    items_df['bag_len'] = items_df['Bags'].map(len)
    must_in_bag = items_df.query(f'bag_len == @{len_of_bag}')
    return must_in_bag


pods_bag = base_bags_query(len_of_bag=PLANES_LEN)

I get an error:

pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: local variable '6' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking Bishwarup Bhattacharjee's answer and modified it a bit.

Since I would like to make a more generic solution.

```py
class AssignBagMusts:
    df = ITEMS_DF
    _bags = BAGS

    @classmethod
    def create_bag_df(cls, bag):
        """
        Add len of string in Bags column to a column named beg_len.
        """
        bags_dict = {}
        df = cls.df[cls.df['bag_len'].apply(lambda bag_len: bag_len == bag)]
        print(df)
        bags_dict.update(df)
        return bags_dict

    @classmethod
    def return_bags_dict(cls, df):
        assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)
        # Assign dictionaries for each bag with its must have items.
        assigned_with_must_bags = {name: cls.create_bag_df(length) for (name, length) in cls._bags.items()}
        # Assign names to each DataFrame created,.
        bags_df_dict = {name: pd.DataFrame(item) for name, item in assigned_with_must_bags.items()}
        return assigned_with_must_bags, bags_df_dict

    @classmethod
    def return_cleaned_df(cls, df_dict):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        df_to_be_dropped, create_bags = cls.return_bags_dict(df=cls.df)
        return cls.return_cleaned_df(create_bags)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AssignBagMusts.run()
```

This way if cls.-bags should receive more bag types and I plan to it later, I have an assignment to bag class ready.